# column-span: all conflicts with overflow and float

Tags: css, google-chrome

The CSS property `column-span: all` seems to stop working as soon as either `overflow: hidden` or `float: left|right` is set on the container:

```
<div>
    <h2>Spanning Header</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor …</p>
</div>
```

and

```
div {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 2em;
    float: left; /* or */
    overflow: hidden;
}
h2 {
    /* will not work */
    -webkit-column-span: all;
}
```

Here is the initial (working) version: http://jsfiddle.net/8y67gqya/
And neither this works: http://jsfiddle.net/rL3m59gk/ nor this: http://jsfiddle.net/rL3m59gk/1/

Is there a logical reason or explanation for this?
Or am I missing something?

**Edit:** This *bug* appears in Google-Chrome *not* Safari… (Can't test IE right now)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Good catch! It only seems to break in Google-Chrome not in Safari  (FireFox doesn't support `column-span` anyway…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting the `column-span` to work in Google Chrome.

Wrap the entire `div` in a block level container `div.wrap` and apply the float or overflow property to it.

Apply the `column` properties to the child `.panel` block.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="panel">
         <h2>Spanning Header</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor s...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the CSS:

```
div.wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
div.panel {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    column-gap: 2em;
}
h2 {
    -webkit-column-span: all;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/aq6gpmf4/

I think that what is happening in your original examples, is that when you apply `float: left` or `overflow: {hidden|auto}` is that you are establishing a new block-formatting context, and this seems to prevent the `column-span` from working properly.

I am not sure why this is the case but the best clue is from the Mozilla documentation page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span#Values

The `column-span: all` value establishes a new block formatting context for the `h2`.  So my guess is that the block-formatting trigger on the `div` due to `float: left` is interfering with the block-formatting trigger due to `column-span: all` on the `h2`, so the algorithm just ignores the `column-span: all` trigger.

The CSS3 specification does not address the precise details of this behavior so I expect that the implementation is left to the discretion of the browser (that is, the people who design and write the relevant code).

**Note**: I did not check this in Safari, but I would expect it to work.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-span "Applies to: block-level elements, except floating and absolutely positioned elements" http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/#column-span "Applies to: in-flow block-level elements" This suggests that when float and column-span are declared on the same element, that float should indeed take precedence and column-span be ignored.

Comment: @BoltClock Well spotted, thanks, this really makes it clear. All the best.

Comment: @BoltClock Feel free to update my answer if you have a moment or the inclination, your comments add gravitas to the mix.